# Angular 4 : Disabled behavior for a button component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, button

I would like to pass the "disabled" behavior to a custom button. The actual behavior with the code below is that the button is disabled when all fields from a form are not filled. But when I fill everything, the button is still disabled. I have the feeling that the "disabled Input" on the component is loaded when the page is loaded but it is never refreshed when the form is completely filled so I cannot click on the button to submit the form. The goal of this component is to be used in several pages with different forms. Is there a way to do this?

Custom Button Html :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled" (click)="onClickButton()">{{ label }}</button>
```

Custon Button TS :

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: ' app-button-loader',
  templateUrl: './button-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-loader.component.css']
})
export class ButtonLoaderComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() disabled: any;
  @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  onClickButton() {
    this.onClick.emit();
  }
}
```

And here is how I call the component :

```
<app-button-loader [disabled]="!demandCreationForm.valid" (onClick)="onSubmit()" [label]="'demand-create.button-submit' | translate"></app-button-loader>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button element to below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disabled" (click)="onClickButton()">{{ label }}</button>
```

Currently, you are directly using the html attribute 'disabled', rather than Angular attribute. Hence the value will not update once page is loaded.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much! I was so focus I completely forgotten those!

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to code like this,

```
<app-button-loader [disabled]="demandCreationForm.invalid" (onClick)="onSubmit()" [label]="'demand-create.button-submit' | translate"></app-button-loader>
```

Comment: The goal of the component is to be re-used by other pages, I cannot hard link it to the actual form (I added the precision on the post).